# Why does my JavaScript forEach muliplication of two elements then setAttribute value to a third element code only run once?

Tags: javascript

Background: I am creating a simple html order form for around 30 items using pure vanilla JavaScript (**no** jQuery) and basic CSS. It will not involve any online payments. New items may be added by my client and they will simply copy paste a block of code for an existing item in the html of the article and give it a new item name. They will not have access to the JavaScript. To avoid potential unwanted duplicates I am using only CSS classes and no element IDs. The form consists of a item name (text), a price and two input fields - one for quantity and one for total, with total being based dynamically on price*quantity as the form is filled.

My query: The quantity and form fields are pre-filled with zeros using a forEach loop and that works fine for all elements as expected. What I cannot get to work is a second loop which calculates the total price based on price x quantity for anything other than the first one it finds.

What am I missing? Is it something to do with the `onblur="calculate"` command in the quantity input element? I have to admit I found this part in someone else's code and haven't used it before. Perhaps I should be using something else.

I have looked at other questions in a similar vein on here (and elsewhere) but they're either using jQuery or other types of JS or tables and so on.

The code is below. TIA:

```js
if (document.querySelector('.order-form')) {
    let qty = document.querySelectorAll('.qty');
  let total = document.querySelectorAll('.total');
    [].forEach.call(qty, function(zero) {
    zero.setAttribute('value','0');
    });
  [].forEach.call(total, function(zero) {
    zero.setAttribute('value','0');
    })
}
calculate = function() {
  let qty = document.querySelectorAll('.qty');
  [].forEach.call(qty, function() {
    let price = document.querySelector('.price').innerText;
    let newprice = parseFloat(price).toFixed(2);
    let qty = document.querySelector('.qty').value;
    let newtotal = parseFloat((newprice)*(qty)).toFixed(2);
    let total = document.querySelector('.total');
    total.setAttribute('value',newtotal);
    });
}
```

```css
.order-form {
  margin: 16px;
  width: 100%;
}
.row {
  width: 100%;
}
.prod {
  margin-top: 16px;
}
.price {
  width: 10%; 
  display: inline-block;
}
.price:before {
  content: "Price: £";
}
.input-style {
  width: 70%; 
  display: inline-block;
}
label {
  padding: 0 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="order-form">
    <div class="prod">Subscription Receipt Book</div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="price" style="width: 10%; display: inline-block;">4.50</div>
    <div class="input-style">
      <label for="qty">Qty:</label><input class="qty" type="text" name="qty" onblur="calculate()" />
      <label for="total_amt">Total: £</label><input class="total" type="text" name="total_amt" /></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" style="width: 100%;">
    <div class="prod">General Receipt Book</div>
    <div class="price" style="width: 10%; display: inline-block;">4.00</div>
   <div class="input-style">
      <label for="qty">Qty:</label><input class="qty" type="text" name="qty" onblur="calculate()" />
      <label for="total_amt">Total: £</label><input class="total" type="text" name="total_amt" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" style="width: 100%;">
    <div class="prod">Minutes book</div>
    <div class="price" style="width: 10%; display: inline-block;">5.50</div>
    <div class="input-style">
      <label for="qty">Qty:</label><input class="qty" type="text" name="qty" onblur="calculate()" />
      <label for="total_amt">Total: £</label><input class="total" type="text" name="total_amt" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you're selecting all the `.price`, `.qty` and `.total` elements in the DOM in the `calculate()` function, *not only* the ones in the same row as the field which was updated.

To fix this you can simply use `closest()` to get the `.row` element relative to the `.qty` which the user updated, and select the necessary fields from there.

Also note that there's several other improvements which should be made to your code.

- Don't use inline event handlers in your HTML, eg. `onblur`, `onclick` etc. They are outdated and not good practice. Bind your events unobtrusively in the JS using `addEventListener()` instead.
- You can call `forEach()` directly on the collections returned by `querySelectorAll()`. This is now well supported so you don't need to mess around converting them to arrays first.
- Set the `value` of the inputs at the time you generate them and append them to the DOM. If you do this after the elements have been created it's likely that they will appear empty for a split second which is unsightly, and should be avoided.
- The `.total` fields default value should be set to 2dp, ie. `0.00`, not just `0`.
- CSS should all be in an external stylesheet. Don't put it in your HTML in a `style` attribute.
- Update the values of your inputs using the `value` property. You don't need to use `setAttribute()` for this.
- The `for` attributes on your `label` elements won't do anything as their values don't match the `id` of any of the inputs. To workaround this, remove the `for` attributes and wrap the `label` elements around the `input`.
- Make the `.total` fields `readonly`, otherwise users can edit them and set whatever price they like.

You can also extend the logic to include an overall total by using `map()` to build an array of the row prices, then `reduce()` to sum them all together.

With all that said, try this:

```js
let calculateTotal = () => {
  let rowPrices = [...document.querySelectorAll('.total')].map(el => parseFloat(el.value));
  let total = rowPrices.reduce((acc, price) => acc += price, 0);
  document.querySelector('#overall_total').textContent = total.toFixed(2);
}

document.querySelectorAll('.qty').forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('input', e => {
    const row = e.target.closest('.row');
    const qty = e.target.value;
    const price = row.querySelector('.price').textContent;
    row.querySelector('.total').value = parseFloat(price * qty).toFixed(2);
    calculateTotal();
  });
});
```

```css
.order-form {
  margin: 16px;
  width: 100%;
}

.row {
  width: 100%;
}

.prod {
  margin-top: 16px;
}

.price {
  width: 10%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.price:before {
  content: "Price: £";
}

.input-style {
  width: 70%;
  display: inline-block;
}

label {
  padding: 0 16px;
}

input {
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="order-form">
  <div class="prod">Subscription Receipt Book</div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="price">4.50</div>
    <div class="input-style">
      <label>
        Qty:
        <input class="qty" type="text" name="qty" value="0" />
      </label>
      <label>
        Total: £
        <input class="total" type="text" name="total_amt" value="0.00" readonly />
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="prod">General Receipt Book</div>
    <div class="price">4.00</div>
    <div class="input-style">
      <label>
        Qty:
        <input class="qty" type="text" name="qty" value="0" />
      </label>
      <label>
        Total: £
        <input class="total" type="text" name="total_amt" value="0.00" readonly />
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="prod">Minutes book</div>
    <div class="price">5.50</div>
    <div class="input-style">
      <label>
        Qty:
        <input class="qty" type="text" name="qty" value="0" />
      </label>
      <label>
        Total: £
        <input class="total" type="text" name="total_amt" value="0.00" readonly />
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<p>
  Total:
  £ <span id="overall_total"></span>
</p>
```

Comment: You star! Thank you so much. The trouble with being a JavaScript learn-it-as-you-go-along kind of person is that I don't know when code that I find online is outdated, such as ```onblur```. One of these days, when I have the time(!), I will start a decent JS course (although I have found relating ```console log``` to the real environment a bit awkward, when I've tried before).

Comment: No problem, glad to help. Just FYI, if you'd like to have your code checked over to check it follow best practices there's https://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Thank you. I'll make a note of that. :-)

Comment: I now need to work out (and I've been trying all day) to get a grand total of the sub-totals. Should I open a new question for that?

Comment: Usually, yes, but I've gone ahead and done it for you anyway :) Check the new function using `map()` and `reduce()`

Comment: So many thanks yet again, @RoryMcCrossan. I tried several different options but ```map()``` and ```reduce()``` weren't in any of them. I was looking at ```push()``` but realised that wasn't going to work. My next web search is definitely going to be looking for the best beginner's basic JavaScript course. I'm using it in the Joomla 4 environment along with PHP.